# PHP5.3: "Call to undefined method" error when calling invoke from class variable

Tags: php, methods, invoke

I have been doing some tests (to replace old code) with the __invoke magic method and I'm not sure this is a bug or not:

Lets suppose we have a class:

```
class Calc {
    function __invoke($a,$b){
        return $a*$b;
    }
}
```

The following is possible and works without any problem:

```
$c = new Calc;
$k = $c;
echo $k(4,5); //outputs 20
```

However if I want to have another class to store an instance of that object, 
this doesn't work:

```
class Test {
    public $k;
    function __construct() {
        $c = new Calc;
        $this->k = $c; //Just to show a similar situation than before
        // $this-k = new Calc; produces the same error.
    }
}
```

The error occurs when we try to call it like:

```
$t = new Test;
echo $t->k(4,5); //Error: Call to undefined method Test::k()
```

I know that a "solution" could be to have a function inside the class Test (named k) to "forward" the call using call_user_func_array but that is not elegant.

I need to keep that instance inside a common class (for design purposes) and be able to call it as function from other classes... any suggestion?

Update:

I found something interesting (at least for my purposes):

If we assign the "class variable" into a local variable it works:

```
$t = new Test;
$m = $t->k;
echo $m(4,5);
```

Comment: Please provide a complete code example which shows your problem. The code sample you say works does not work and the code sample you say gives a problem works.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad... I update it. Sjoerd: Did that example worked for you? strange :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do `$test->k()`, PHP thinks you are calling a method on the `$test` instance. Since there is no method named `k()`, PHP throws an exception. What you are trying to do is make PHP return the public property `k` and invoke that, but to do so you have to assign `k` to a variable first. It's a matter of dereferencing.

You could add the magic `__call` method to your `Test` class to check if there is a property with the called method name and invoke that instead though:

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
    if(property_exists($this, $method)) {
        $prop = $this->$method;
        return $prop();
    }
}
```

I leave adding the arguments to the invocation to you.
You might also want to check if the property [`is_callable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php).

But anyway, then you can do

```
$test->k();
```

Comment: We posted at the same time... Yes maybe that could help... If I don't find any other better alternative I will mark your answer as good.

Answer (score 7):

PHP thinks you want to call a method k on instance $t when you do:

```
$t->k(4, 5)
```

which is perfectly reasonable. You can use an intermediate variable to call the object:

```
$b = $t->k;
$b(4, 5);
```

See also [bug #50029](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50029), which describes your issue.

Comment: (+1). Now it is getting clear for me. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use method syntax (like $foo->bar() ) to call closures or objects with __invoke, since the engine always thinks this is a method call. You could simulate it through __call:

```
function __call($name, $params) {
  if(is_callable($this->$name)) {
    call_user_func_array($this->$name, $params);
  }
}
```

but it would not work as-is.

Answer (score 0):

If you call $test->k() PHP will search for a method called "k" on the $test instance and obviously it will throws an Exception.

To resolve this problem you can create a getter of the property "k"

```
class Test {
    public $k;

    function __construct() {
        $c = new Calc;
        $this->k = $c; //Just to show a similar situation than before
        // $this-k = new Calc; produces the same error.
    }

    public function getK() {
        return $this->k;
    }
}
```

So now you can use the functor in this way:

```
$t = new Test();
echo $t->getK()(4,5);
```